# Error reached end of file while parsing

Tags: java

This is my Java class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class first {

    public static void main(String args[]);

    int right_number, user_input;

    right_number = 6;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
    user_input = input.nextInt();

    if(user_input = right_number) {
        System.out.println("That is the right number!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Aww, try again by typing java first into commad line.");
    }
}
```

It keeps saying this:

> Error reached end of file while parsing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have o use `==`if you compare values: `if(user_input == right_number)`

Comment: The code in question does not compile, which is a stretch for "simple typo" close reason, but anyway this kind of questions is really better answered by redirecting to [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 3):

This is the first problem:

```
public static void main(String args[]);
```

You're not actually declaring a method body here. It should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Method body goes here
}
```

You should only use a `;` at the end of a method declaration for abstract methods (including those which are implicitly abstract in an interface). If you haven't got to abstract methods yet, just ignore that for the moment - basically use braces to provide a method body.

(The `String[] args` vs `String args[]` isn't a problem as such, but this version is preferred as a matter of style... as would naming your class `First` rather than `first`... there are various other style issues here, but I'll leave it at that for now.)

The fact that your class "tries" to end directly after an `else` statement should be a warning bell - an `else` statement can only appear in a method or constructor, so there *has* to be a brace to close that method/constructor and then a brace to close the class declaration itself. Likewise, the indentation should warn you of that - assuming you're using an IDE to perform the indentation, any time you find yourself writing method body statements which are only one level of indentation further than the class declaration, that suggests you have a problem somewhere - look up the file to see where it starts.

Comment: i am a total beggint so dont hate for asking this questionn what is a method body

Comment: @MufasaKing: A "method body" is the part of a method which does the actual work - it's the bit that in your case would start with `int right_number, user_input;`. If you're *very* new to Java, however, I'd advise getting a good book and reading it carefully - Stack Overflow is good for specific questions, but it's really not a good place to learn the basics of the language.

Answer (score 1):

The code has a lot of mistakes like :

1.

```
public static void main(String args[]);
```

it should be

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
// every thing should be inside this
}
```

2.

You have declared your scanner object to be `in` , but you are doing `user_input = input.nextInt();` , which should be `user_input = in.nextInt();`

3.

`if(user_input = right_number)` should say `if(user_input == right_number)` because `=` is the assignment operator, to compare you should use `==`

**This is the right code :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int right_number, user_input;
        right_number = 6;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
        user_input = in.nextInt();

        if(user_input == right_number) {
            System.out.println("That is the right number!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Aww, try again by typing java first into commad line.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what was wrong - nor indented the code to how it *should* look, which doesn't help.

Comment: It's still indented horribly - and personally I'd fix the style issues at the same time, if you're going to rewrite the whole code.

Comment: I am sorry, is the answer wrong?
Or it's the styling?

Any specific styling / formatting guide ll be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: It's not *wrong* - but it's *still* indented nastily, in a way which doesn't help the OP to see how you should *expect* to see a method body indented. Will fix it myself now...

Comment: @JonSkeet is it not important to remove the warning of `Resource leak`.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks :)

ll keep in mind from now onward :)